# Installing pythontex for use with Sublime Text3

Tags: texlive, sublime-text, pythontex, latextools

Having a little trouble getting my head around the proper installation of `pythontex` package. I've added it to the preamble in my thesis file and tried running with the example nested inside the `pycode` environment:

```
#Long preamble with a custom document class based on report style
\usepackage{pythontex}
# bunch of other packages

\begin{document}
#some text
\begin{pycode}
print(r'\begin{center}`')
print(r'\textit{A message from Python!}`')
print(r'\end{center}`')
\end{pycode}
\end{document}
```

but despite the document compiling fine with minor warnings, Python is either not executed or not printed.
There are also issues with syntax not getting highlighted upon copying directly from PDFs into the tex file.
Having read through the installation notes in the documentation I made sure to do the following.

- installed Python 3.9.6 (I also have it installed via Anaconda Navigator)
- installed Pygments package through Command Prompt
- made sure I have the `caption` package

The builder in Sublime Text 3 editor runs pdflatex -> biblatex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex with texlive distro fed through LateXTools.

Would someone mind providing a bit of guidance on where to start checking where it's going wrong? Do I need to call some other packages? Check my Python installation?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, with PythonTeX you have to compile the document (at least) like so: (any)latex -> pythontex -> (any)latex. I dont know how to set that up in Sublime Text, I use only Texworks, where settings for pythontex build can be taken from pdflatex settings, so maybe use build settings for pdflatex and just change running program to "pythontex".

Comment: @TomášKruliš yes I suspected build engine needs reconfiguring. ST3 allows setting a custom builder but wants a path to the file which presumably has all the relevant comments for running the correct sequence. I imagine if one runs pdflatex -> biber -> pythontex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex that would be sufficient? But I am none the wiser where the builders are stored or how to write a custom file yet

Comment: I found the relevant LaTeXTools plugin documentation where one can customise this - https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/available-builders/#customizing-the-build-system
@TomášKruliš what command do you pass to run `pythontex` as part of your builder?

Comment: Simply inserting `pythontex` into the program queue doesn't help. The `.log` file indicates `pythontex` was executed and typeset, and that `.pytxmcr` file was created. So Sublime Text seems to be running the package fine, but I am getting no output in the final PDF

Comment: Well, the setting is simply to run `pythontex filename` in subprocess/console. If it seems not to be working, try to run it in command line.

Comment: I've now ran it in the command line and it issued a `program not found (not part of TeX Live): python.exe` error. So I reinstalled Python 3.9.6 making sure I add it to PATH. I've reran `pdflatex` -> `pythontex` -> `pdflatex` in command line and the PDF now has output. So this must be a ST3-LaTeXTools configuration issue?

Comment: The command passed through is - ` "builder_settings": {"windows": {     "script_commands": ["pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Thesis.tex",                 "bibtex Thesis.tex", "pythontex Thesis.tex", "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Thesis.tex", "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode Thesis.tex"] } } `

Comment: @Wolfe79 What does `python` give you on the terminal? Is the python executable possible called `python3` instead of `python`?